# How to put condition for hosts in ansible playbook using ec2 dynamic inventory

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-inventory

In my Ansible playbook I want to use host with condition. For example: if the tag_Name_WebServer and tage_Environment_development.

So it should return me the list of the servers which are belongs to development environment and should have the Name tag as Webserver. Please help me to fix it.

I have tried with:

```
---
- name: Development WebServer Configuration
  hosts: tag_Name_WebServer:tag_Name_Development
```

But the result I am getting is the instance list of all from WebServer and all from Environment Development. How to put the proper condition?

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution. The condition should be like below:

```
---
- name: Development WebServer Configuration
  hosts: tag_Name_WebServer:&tag_Name_Development
```

You will get the intersection of the two group in this case.

Comment: This is documented on the [Ansible Intro Patterns](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_patterns.html#patterns) page.